Policy on swear words
This is related to the policy on potentially NSFW questions, but I wanted to know the community's stance on this particular topic.
I don't think we should ban questions about swearing, because it's still part of the language, but we need some strict guidelines to handle them the best way.
We should be allowing questions asked in good faith, but have a way to determine if the question is just there for shock value. Any ideas?

Note: when these guidelines are decided, I'd like to ask who has the privilege to close/flag to use it. While there are some moderators on this site, privileges exist for a reason, you moderate more and more as you earn reputation. And even if you don't have it, "flagging to close" is helpful for the others.

Hi @Alenanno, is there an active chat room that users may further discuss issues like this? The only available chat room now appears to be low on activity. Also, is the blog for this site launched? I would be willing to write some entries to address such issues in greater details. Thank you!

Things deemed NSFW could always be: ">!"-ed. (Spoilered-out(?)).

I was actually going to post a similar question to yours a few weeks ago, particularly in response to this question. However, after doing some research, I think questions about swearing is not necessarily inappropriate. This, for instance, seems to be a valid question.
As such, I believe that as long as the intention to asking the question is clearly specified and is perfectly valid, the question should be fine with swear words.

I was thinking we could use the EL&U policy:

No swearing in titles (titles can be shared in many ways and the local formatting might not properly show the entire title).
Swearing is allowed in body questions as long as the question is legit.

Using the example in Hellion's answer:

The primary restriction is that you should post in a polite, civil manner, which means that you should not actually use swear words or offensive terms as part of your general presentation.
okay:

What's a more polite way to tell someone to "get the fuck out"?

not okay:

Why the fuck should I have to conform to some anonymous asshole's stupid rules about civility?


I find it to be a sensible policy.
